# Positioning flex box at the end

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, flexbox

I have two inner boxes in a flex box container. As you can see on the picture
[image]

An the code

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="space-around center" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">

  <div layout="row" flex="30" style="border: 1px solid #F39814;">

    <div layout="row" style="border: 1px solid #440044;align-items: flex-start;">
      <h2>Project</h2>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" style="border: 1px solid #ffff00;align-items: flex-end;">
      <p>Sign In</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</md-toolbar>
```

I want to place the **sign in box** on the right side and **the project box** should stay on the left side. I try with statement `align-items: flex-end;` to place **the sign in box** on the right side, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

I am using angular material design and try as follow too:

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="space-around center" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">

  <div layout="row" flex="30" style="border: 1px solid #F39814;">

    <div layout="row" layout-align="end center" style="border: 1px solid #440044;">
      <h2>Project</h2>
    </div>

    <div layout="row" layout-align="end center" style="border: 1px solid #ffff00;">
      <p>Sign In</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</md-toolbar>
```

but it does not work too.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty flex item between them with the following css property:

```
flex: 1 0 auto
```

But I can not help you to translate that in the angular syntax.

[a demo](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=flex-start&align-content=space-around&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=0&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting an empty `<span flex>` element between your two inner `<div>`?

This is how I seperate left/right aligned toolbar-tools.

Edit: If you don't want that extra `<span>` tag in your markup you could also try to set `layout-align="space-between"` on your outer `<div>`.